# If StreetView is not available for a specified latlong, how to get the nearest available StreetView?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-street-view

here is my code

```
private static LatLng STREETVIEW = new LatLng(51.503635, -0.119781);
StreetViewPanorama streetViewPanorama;
StreetViewPanoramaView mStreetViewPanoramaView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_street_view);

        mStreetViewPanoramaView = findViewById(R.id.streetviewpanorama);
        mStreetViewPanoramaView.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(this);

        mStreetViewPanoramaView.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        mStreetViewPanoramaView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
    this.streetViewPanorama = panorama;
    panorama.setPosition(STREETVIEW, 20, StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR);
    streetViewPanorama.setOnStreetViewPanoramaChangeListener(this);
}


    @Override
public void onStreetViewPanoramaChange(StreetViewPanoramaLocation streetViewPanoramaLocation) {
    if (streetViewPanoramaLocation != null && streetViewPanoramaLocation.links != null) {
            Toast.makeText(StreetViewActivity.this, "StreetView available here.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(StreetViewActivity.this, "Street View not available on this location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //here, how to get nearest streetView within 100 meter distance .?
    }
}
```

if streetview not available on current latlong. 
i want nearest streetView if available in nearest within 100 or any specified meter.

how may i achieve this in android app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Streetview are retrieved using latlng and radius. You are calling this method:

```
panorama.setPosition(STREETVIEW, 20, StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR);
```

which gets streetviews within 20 meters.

Here is signature of the method: `public void setPosition (LatLng position, int radius, StreetViewSource source)`

You need to pass 100 or any other number you want as radius and it'll find streetview within that radius around the given latlng.

For example, if you wanna get streetviews within 100m radius, call this:

```
panorama.setPosition(STREETVIEW, 100, StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR);
```

Comment: perfect answer.

Comment: StreetViewSource.OUTDOOR what does it mean ?
this has 2 options OUTDOOR and DEFAULT ? i wanna get to know difference in both.

Comment: OUTDOOR limits search to display only streetviews that are outside. While DEFAULT, does not limit it. It can display both indoor and outdoor streetviews. Here is doc for further details:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/StreetViewSource.html